# How to check if element is defined in a list of objects in ansible

Tags: arrays, list, ansible

I would like to run an ansible Task only if Object element exist in a list.

that's is the Array

```
local_users:
  - name: user1
    sshkey: key
    sudo: yes
    allow_remote_login: yes
  - name: user2
    sshkey: key
    sudo: yes
    allow_remote_login: yes
```

and that my task:

```
- name: Set up authorized keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item.sshkey }}"
  loop: "{{ local_users }}"
  when: local_users.sshkey is defined
```

but ansible tell me that ssh_key is not defined:

```
"skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking for `item.sshkey` instead of `local_users.sshkey` while iterating.

Example:

Using your variables, display a message when `sshkey` is defined:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}, has key"
    loop: "{{ local_users }}"
    when: item.sshkey is defined
```

Similarly, you should have:

```yaml
- name: Set up authorized keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
    key: "{{ item.sshkey }}"
  loop: "{{ local_users }}"
  when: item.sshkey is defined
```